# Где можно посмотреть какие View и ViewGroup есть в Android?

Tags: android

Где можно посмотреть какие `View` и `ViewGroup` есть в Android?

Просто в процессе гугления открываю для себя все новые и новые элементы. Может есть сайт со списком или что-то в этом духе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно есть такой сайт - http://developer.android.com . Там **есть всё**, что только вам захочется узнать про андроид.

В частности, под `View` вы скорее всего имеете ввиду класс `Widget` в котором собраны такие компоненты, как `TextView`, `EditText`, `Checkbox` или компоновщики, вроде `LinearLayout` и прочее, что можно увидеть на экране и которые являются наследниками класса `View`.

[Полный список](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) **всех** элементов интерфейса Android, со **всеми** их конструкторами, методами, интерфейсами, константами, xml-атрибутами, иерархией наследования и прочее прочее прочее - настоящий клад для разработчика.